# How to get different point in ipython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

```
plt.plot(jd1,spd1)
plt.plot(jd1,spd1,marker="o",markerfacecolor="r",linestyle='None')
plt.show()

print 'click on any obviously bad points and then press the enter key.'
badpoints=ginput(n=0)

index_badpoints=[]
badpoints_num=len(badpoints)
for i in range(len(badpoints)):
     index_badpoints.append(int(np.interp(badpoints[i][0],
                                          yeardays,
                                          range(len(yeardays)))))

print index_badpoints #always[107,107,107...]
```

The question is whichever points I click on, I can only get the points which indexs are 107.
Can somebody to help me figure the problem out?

Comment: Post `badpoints` and `yeardays` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not been able to test your version but I can show you how I would solve this:

```
badpoints = np.array(ginput(n=0))
index_badpoints = np.argmin(abs(np.subtract(badpoints[:,0],yeardays)),axis=1)
```

This calculates for badpoints the distance along the x-axis from the yeardays and returns the index of the closest one.

Comment: thank you very much for your methods.It's very helpful for me:)